# Getting error in configuring s3 Sink conector

Tags: apache-kafka

I have cloned landoop fast-data-dev docker repo from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/Landoop/fast-data-dev).

and built the image using command `docker build --tag=landoop .`

After building the image, I ran it using:

```
docker run --rm -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081-8083:8081-8083 -p 9581-9585:9581-9585 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=10.10.X.X -e DEBUG=1 -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX landoop
```

Once the UI was up, I tried to create a s3 sink connection but it failed saying:

```
   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/libnss3.so
```

Also I don't see the `libnss3.so` file in the location. However if I run the docker container directly  using the command below, I can see the file in the location and there is no error when creating the s3 sink connector.

```
  docker run --rm --net=host landoop/fast-data-dev
```

Has anyone faced this error?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question so that others can benefit,if it's not appropriate please leave a comment and I will make it a comment. I figured out that the `libnss3` library was missing from `debian` image and had to install while building the image. For this I edited the `setp-and-run.sh` and added the `libnss3`, the script looks like :

```
 FROM debian as compile-lkd
 RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
       unzip \
       wget \
       libnss3 \
```